# Is this a proper Implementation of database connection and autocloseable resources?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, autocloseable

I have a program that reads from a MySQL database table, iterates through the resultSet and returns the row data for a particular userId in a List. With the help of all the available internet resources, I managed to create something that works but I'm not sure whether my implementation is correct or not. Below are my DbConnection and DaoImpl classes.

DbConnection.java

```
    /**
 * This class is responsible for creating a new database connection using the declared URL, USER and PASSWORD.
 */

package dbconnection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DbConnection implements AutoCloseable {
    public static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
    public static final String USER = "root";
    public static final String PWD = "root";

    private Connection conn;

    /**
     * An empty constructor that takes no arguments and creates a new Connection using DriverManager.getConnection.
     * The connection is initiated inside a try-with resources with SQLException catch.
     */

    public DbConnection() {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PWD);
            System.out.println("Connection Established.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't Connect!! " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    //Return the current connection
    public Connection getConn() {
        return conn;
    }


    //close
    public void close() {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
                System.out.println("Connection Closed");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't close Connection " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

TiedostoDaoImpl.java

```
 import dbconnection.DbConnection;
import pojos.Tiedosto;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TiedostoDaoImpl implements TiedostoDAO {
    final String TABLE_TIEDOSTO = "tiedosto";
    final String COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_NAME = "nimi";
    final String COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_SIZE = "koko_tavua";
    final String COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_CONTENT = "sisalto";
    final String COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_CUSTOMER_ID = "hlo_id";
    final String COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_MINIOUPLOAD = "minioupload";

    final String QUERY_TIEDOSTO = "SELECT " + COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_NAME + ", " + COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_CUSTOMER_ID + ", " + COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_SIZE + ", " + COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_CONTENT +
            " FROM " + TABLE_TIEDOSTO + " WHERE " + COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_CUSTOMER_ID + " = ?";

    final String UPDATE_TIEDOSTO = "UPDATE " + TABLE_TIEDOSTO + " SET " + COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_MINIOUPLOAD + " = 1 WHERE " + COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_CUSTOMER_ID + " = ?";


    private DbConnection dbConnection = new DbConnection();
    private Connection databaseConnection;

    public TiedostoDaoImpl() {
        try {
            databaseConnection = dbConnection.getConn();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem Connecting to Database! " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    //This method queries tiedosto table and returns the data as a List.
    @Override
    public List<Tiedosto> getDetails(int userId) throws SQLException {
        List<Tiedosto> files;
        try (PreparedStatement selectFromTiedosto = databaseConnection.prepareStatement(QUERY_TIEDOSTO)) {
            selectFromTiedosto.setInt(1, userId);
            try (ResultSet results = selectFromTiedosto.executeQuery()) {
                files = new ArrayList<>();
                while (results.next()) {
                    Tiedosto myFile = new Tiedosto();
                    myFile.setCustomerId(results.getInt(COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_CUSTOMER_ID));
                    myFile.setFileName(results.getString(COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_NAME));
                    myFile.setFileSize(results.getInt(COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_SIZE));
                    myFile.setContent(results.getBlob(COLUMN_TIEDOSTO_CONTENT));
                    files.add(myFile);
                }
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
```

when I run the program I get an output like this:
[image]

When I run the program it says "Connection Established" and returns data, but it doesn't say anything about closing the connection. I need to know if I'm implementing this whole thing correctly. Can someone please help?

Comment: Your `DbConnection` class functions as a poor data source + connection handle. Consider instead using a `DataSource` implementation (optionally with a connection pool) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `DbConnection` in the `try-with-resource` statement, maybe something like...

```
try (DbConnection db = new DbConnection(); PreparedStatement selectFromTiedosto = db.getConn().prepareStatement(QUERY_TIEDOSTO)) {
    // ...
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will auto close both the `DbConnection` and the `PreparedStatement` (although closing the connection will automatically close the `PreparedStatement` anyway).

Drawback, each time you use it this way, you're creating a new `Connection` to the database, which may take time.  It might be more preferable to use a shut-down hook or connection pool instead, depending on what you are actually doing

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up for me. Now I have some sort of clear understanding on how try-with-resources actually work.